# Using log4j for logging with logback

Tags: java, logging, logback

I want to use log4j(not slf4j) for logging along with logback.jar. Is there anyway doing that? I am working on a web service that consumes log4j and I am intended to use logback.jar along with that.

Comment: So you want to use the Log4j *API* in your code, but you don't actually want the *logging* done by Log4j, but instead want the logging done by Logback? Did you want to use the *Log4j 1.2* or the *Log4j 2* API?

Comment: No, I am using log4j API for logging but with that, I want to use logback for other implementations.

Comment: Other implementations of what? Log4j and Logback are both full logger implementations, competing with each other. Why would you want two entire *separate* logger implementations at the same time?

Comment: Actually, The existing code uses Log4j 1.2 and I want to add a new jar that will use Logback API. Is it possible to add some jar like log4j-over-slf4j to keep using the same logger without changing the previous code?

Comment: The new jar uses Logback *directly*, not SLF4J? That's very unusual. I didn't even know Logback had it's own API, I thought it always used SLF4J as its API.

Answer (score 4):

The slf4j project provides some "bridge" jars for dealing with legacy logging.  According to http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#log4j-over-slf4j:

> log4j-over-slf4j
>
> ---
>
> SLF4J ship with a module called log4j-over-slf4j. It allows log4j users to migrate existing applications to SLF4J without changing a single line of code but simply by replacing the log4j.jar file with log4j-over-slf4j.jar, as described below.
>
> How does it work?
>
> ---
>
> The log4j-over-slf4j module contains replacements of most widely used log4j classes, namely org.apache.log4j.Category, org.apache.log4j.Logger, org.apache.log4j.Priority, org.apache.log4j.Level, org.apache.log4j.MDC, and org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator. These replacement classes redirect all work to their corresponding SLF4J classes.
>
> To use log4j-over-slf4j in your own application, the first step is to locate and then to replace log4j.jar with log4j-over-slf4j.jar. Note that you still need an SLF4J binding and its dependencies for log4j-over-slf4j to work properly.
>
> In most situations, replacing a jar file is all it takes in order to migrate from log4j to SLF4J.
>
> Note that as a result of this migration, log4j configuration files will no longer be picked up. If you need to migrate your log4j.properties file to logback, the log4j translator might be of help. For configuring logback, please refer to its manual.
>
> When does it not work?
>
> ---
>
> The log4j-over-slf4j module will not work when the application calls log4j components that are not present in the bridge. For example, when application code directly references log4j appenders, filters or the PropertyConfigurator, then log4j-over-slf4j would be an insufficient replacement for log4j. However, when log4j is configured through a configuration file, be it log4j.properties or log4j.xml, the log4j-over-slf4j module should just work fine.

In your case, what you would need to do is to add `log4j-over-slf4j` together with  the `log4j12`, `logback-classic` and `logback-core` JARs.  You would also need to reimplement the relevant parts of the log4j logging config file in the logback configs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. In your case it will be combination of log4j and SLF4j.
SLF4j is a facade library which provide abstraction for logging libraries like log4j, logback, java.util.logger and don't do actual logging.
So, basically SLF4j serves as a simple facade or abstraction for various logging frameworks allowing the end user to plug in the desired logging framework at deployment time.

For implementation you can refer:  https://medium.com/@krishankantsinghal/logback-slf4j-log4j2-understanding-them-and-learn-how-to-use-d33deedd0c46